# LaTeX indentation in vim

Tags: indentation, vim

Does there exist a good [indentation](/questions/tagged/indentation) option/plugin for [vim](/questions/tagged/vim)? I tried different combinations of `autoindent`, `smartindent` and `cindent`, what I get is:

```
\begin{tabular}{ c }
foo \\
    bar
    \end{tabular}
```

but what I'd like to have is (or something similar, my requirements on [indentation](/questions/tagged/indentation) are not that strict):

```
\begin{tabular}{ c }
    foo \\
    bar
\end{tabular}
```

I also tried setting

```
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
```

but with no avail.

Comment: You can use a combination of snippets (containing the indentation) and `autoindent` (to continue the indentation on new lines).

Comment: Have a look at `latexindent` (disclaimer: I'm the author). Here's a [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM) demonstration- documentation is on `ctan`, and it is part of `texlive`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used the indenting of the [vim](/questions/tagged/vim) plugin [latex-suite](/questions/tagged/latex-suite). It works perfectly. Downside of it is, that [latex-suite](/questions/tagged/latex-suite) is quite heavy-weight and if someone is not interested in all the other stuff, then it doesn't make sense to install the whole package. But I am sure getting the indenting out of this package shouldn't be too difficult.

[latexindent](/questions/tagged/latexindent)  [looks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_AMmNVg5WM) nice, too. I opted for the [latex-suite](/questions/tagged/latex-suite) plugin because it works internally in [vim](/questions/tagged/vim), while [latexindent](/questions/tagged/latexindent) is an external [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) script.